# Homebrew using asdf-vm for dependencies

Tags: homebrew

I've recently been forced to re-setup my laptop, and after installing homebrew and asdf, I got to installing other dependencies.

First I installed Python 3.11 and then some dependencies with brew. It's at this point I realised that homebrew needed to download Python 3.11, despite ASDF having downloaded it just before.

Now I do realize the 2 are separate entities, and due to the nature of asdf this may not always be possible, but is there any way to have brew on install review the asdf install directory and if a dependency can be met using one of those dependencies, then it'll use that rather then installing a copy of a dependency already on the system?

I've found https://docs.brew.sh/Building-Against-Non-Homebrew-Dependencies though this appears to be more specific to building your own formulas in homebrew. I suspect this answers my question in that "No they don't support this", but some more experienced brew users insights would be helpful